# 102 files copy identical range from each to one worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have approximately 102 .xlsx files. From each of it i want to copy identical range (a column) and then paste to a single worksheet. As a result i want to have those columns in one worksheet adjacent to each other.

I do not want to do that by simple opening and closing of a workbook.

I would prefer this to work fast i.e. is there any other method than opening and closing each file? What would be the fastest approach to do that? Maybe some possibility to copy without opening of the file?

I have managed to clear my original code which was:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Wiersz = 102
For i = 1 To Wiersz
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=Kat & "U" & i & ".xlsx"
    Range("D11:D210").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Obl").Range("E1:E200").Offset(0, i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Workbooks("U" & i & ".xlsx").Close
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Anybody any idea how to improve my code? It runs for about a minute i want it to be seconds.

Comment: Using ADODB to perform an SQL (a SQL?) query on the files would save the need to open the files (in Excel), but it seems like a lot of effort to go to.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have tried opening and closing 102 files separately. To slow.

Comment: Paste your code into the question, and we might be able to see if something is slowing it down.

Comment: are they all of similar naming conventions i.e. filex-1, filex-2 etc?

Comment: Yep names are xxx1.xlsx, xxx2.xlsx and so forth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this an modify to your requirements:

```
Sub Test()

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Dim StrFile As String
Dim StrPath As String
Dim icounter As Integer

'StrPath = "enter file path here\"
'StrFile = Dir("enter file path here\*.xlsx*")

For icounter = 1 To 4 'or 102 in your case
    StrPath = Left(StrPath, Len(StrPath) - 2) & icounter & "\"
    StrFile = Dir(StrPath & "*.xlsx*")
        Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("whatever").Range("whatever").Copy 'or whatever
            Set Fldrwkbk = Workbooks.Open(StrPath & StrFile, False, False)
            Fldrwkbk.Sheets("whatever").Range("whatever").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Fldrwkbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
            StrFile = Dir
        Loop
Next icounter

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Change the Do While loop to suit whatever you want to do. Use this as a starting base! :)

Let me know how this goes and we can modify to your liking

Comment: Do you mind feeding back how this worked for you? :)